# ">" mark in the project name in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

[image]

I'm trying to build  eclipse source that has a lot of projects. I found that some of the projects show ">" mark. What is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` means it is dirty.

As it says in in [git submodules explained](http://longair.net/blog/2010/06/02/git-submodules-explained/)

> Versions 1.7.0 and later of git contain an [annoying change](http://github.com/git/git/commit/ee6fc514f2df821c2719cc49499a56ef2fb136b0) in the behavior of git submodule.
>   **Submodules are now regarded as dirty if they have any modified files or untracked files**, whereas previously it would only be the case if HEAD in the submodule pointed to the wrong commit.

Here is some extra information on what each of the icons mean:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a text decoration from the CVS or SVN (or other) team support, which indicates an outgoing change: there is at least one file in the project that has been modified since the last CVS/SVN update.

Go to Preferences and type "Label decoration" in the filter box to show where these decorations might come from.